# Blender knife tool options

Tags: modeling, edges, faces, operator, knife-tool

So I'm 3d modeling a logo and there's one oddly shaped part that needs to be extruded. I am trying to use the knife tool to cut it out, but every time I finish it deletes the face. In the operator I can see the option that I obviously need to change, but it's grayed out saying redo unsupported. What do I do?

Comment: **Knife** tool is interactive one so you change its [options](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html#options) while it's activated (i.e. before confirm). Still I'm not sure why it deletes the face once cut is finished. Could you add example screenshot ?

Answer (score 4):

### N-gons with a hole

Currently holed-ngons (e.g. a doughnut section) are not supported. If in the cutting process you are creating one of those, the software will try its best in finding a way to continue anyway (in this case by splitting the ngon in two and as a side effect deleting th inner face).

In the picture below you can see the difference of behaviour of the command upon the same mesh but with different topology:

[image]

I suggest to continue knife projecting the shape as you were doing and then simply re-fill the boundary with a new face. Just select the hole boundary and press <kbd>F</kbd> or with another method (e.g. **fill holes** operator).

Comment: Here's an old forum post about the topic: https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-328732.html