# How can I dissolve these remaining edges?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I can't dissolve these two edges because it's a looped surface, but is there a way? [image]

Comment: AFAIK Blender currently (2.77a) doesn't support N-gons with a hole, so I think it's not possible. Related: [Blender knife tool options](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48777/blender-knife-tool-options/48779#48779)

Comment: as above. But as you did on the base flat surface, you could "keep" two edges on each ring on the central zone, and dissolve each ring obtaining two ngons...