# Filling objects doesn't go well

Tags: objects

As you can see here, I want to fill the hole, but in hole is a circle, so when I press F... this happens

My question is how to fill it without making it fill the circle too? Since I have to use more and more faces which complicates texturing the model.

Comment: Try to fill an half, and then the other half. Ngons with holes are not currently supported: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48777/blender-knife-tool-options/48779#48779

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of ways to connect a hole. The only rule you have to obey is that at least one edge has to connect the inner edgeloop with the outer edgeloop. Two or more are usually better.

If your mesh doesn't have to be watertight, and polycount is important to you, then you can even make a very simple hole as long as it gets covered by the other geometry (lower left).

[image: holy...]

Comment: I know that, i was just trying to find a way about how to do it without an edge.

Comment: @DraganPavlovic Then the answer would be: learn C++ and rebuild Blender's entire mesh data structure, or something like that ( : Booleans don't relly count.