# Having trouble joining faces

Tags: mesh, faces, subdivision-surface

[image]

Hi
sadly im having a little of trouble and can't find anything on the internet on how to solve this.
The faces are splitted with these black lines, anyone knows how to merge them?

Comment: It is not possible to create n-gon face with hole.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48779/2214 or here
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211249/2214